# Can't call function with onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, html

Why doesn't this work?

html :

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <button onclick="test21()">test</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
function test21(){
    console.log("yey");
}
```

Comment: check if you included the js correctly https://plnkr.co/edit/Q0NnFQoWL5kEp2BsglrT?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

That works fine. Here's a JSBin to prove it.

**http://jsbin.com/luxesazibi/edit?html,output**

More than likely you haven't loaded your script in your HTML. Where are you putting your javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single function that calls both of those, and then use it in the event.

```
function myFunction(){
    pay();
    cls();
}
```

And then, for the button:

```
<input id="btn" type="button" value="click" onclick="myFunction();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not included the script in html file.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>test</title>
   <script>
     function test21(){
      console.log("yey");
      }
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <button onclick="test21()">test</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Above code snippet will run fine.
Use inspector (ctrl+shift+I) to launch console and click on the button to get results.